# weird short delay when left clicking an item in Windows 7 File Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, delay, mouse-click

I have a weird problem with my windows 7 laptop: left clicking an item in the File Explorer doesn't select the item immediately but after a short delay, like half a second. I tried to investigate, but have no clue at all. Any thoughts?

Here are more observations:

1. The problem doesn't occur all the time. It seems that the problem starts to occur after the machine has been running for a short while, around 20-30 minutes.
2. Right clicking or navigation using the keyboard in the File Explorer doesn't have the issue, always getting response immediately.
3. Using a File Explorer alternative program, like FreeCommanderXE, doesn't have the issue.
4. Left clicking anything else in the Windows doesn't seem to have the issue, like clicking the icons on the desktop and taskbar.

I originally thought that the SSD drive I put in the laptop replacing the old HDD was the source, but based on the observations above. I ruled it out. Any other thoughts? mouse driver, Windows File Explorer or any shell extension?

I have done disk check and memory test. No problem was found. Please help. It's very annoying and weird.

Answer (score 0):

Was the issue occurred before?
Have you installed other software or changed the system setting before the symptom occurred?

We could check the issue in a clean boot environment to avoid the influence from third party software.
Use the following tool to check for third party context menu, disable or uninstall the related program then check the symptom again.

ShellMenuView v1.36 - Disable/enable context menu items of Explorer
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Best regards,
Joy.

Comment: Thanks, @Joy. I actually tried ShellMenuView, but I didn't have a clue about what to do as the records there look like secret code. I don't want to mess up other parts of the system.